# What is the Wordpress Pinecone sitting on top of?

Tags: themes, images, headers, theme-twenty-eleven

Does anybody know where wordpress gets their banner images? Perhaps we could find the original photo? I'm curious just what exactly this pine cone is sitting on top of.

[image http://img828.imageshack.us/img828/9583/pinecone.jpg](http://img828.imageshack.us/img828/9583/pinecone.jpg)

Comment: looks like a granite post or wall to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Header images come from Matt Mullenweg's photos http://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/17729

It's unreal to find if it was posted anywhere with proper description (man snaps gigabytes of pics), go ask him.

Comment: Gigabytes nothing... terabytes. Still, it's probably in his gallery somewhere: http://ma.tt/gallery/